# Relation between Areas

Tags: geometry, area, quadrilateral

Given a quadrilateral $ABCDEF$, where $B$ is the midpoint of $\overline{AC}$ and $E$ is the midpoint of $\overline{FD}$, prove the relation $$a+d = c+b,$$ where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ denote the respective areas of triangle as denoted by the following figure:

[image: Quadrilateral cut into triangles.]

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What theorems do you know that you think will be useful?  We are happy to give hints, but you have to tell us what you've tried.

Comment: Well actually I have tried using the fact that the line BE forms the median of EBD and triangle AEC so the Ar(ABE)=Ar(ADE) , I then did tried using these in order to get but failed so I am here

Answer (score 2):

Let $O_1$ be $AE$ intersect $BF$, $O_2$ be $BD$ intersect $CE$.
$$S_{FO_1A}+S_{DO_2C}=S_{BO_1E}+S_{BO_2E} \Leftrightarrow$$
$$S_{FO_1A}+S_{O_1AB}+S_{DO_2C}+S_{O_2BC}=S_{BO_1E}+S_{O_1AB}+S_{BO_2E}+S_{O_2BC}
 \Leftrightarrow$$ $$ S_{FAB}+S_{DBC}=S_{AEC}$$
Let $FH_1, EH_2, DH_3$ be perpendiculars, dropped onto line $AC$. Then we need to prove only $FH_1+DH_3=2EH_2$ and it holds because of $EH_2$ being midline of $FH_1H_3D$.
[image]

Comment: Could you just post a image of your labelled diagram